# comparing two arrays of different lengths and returning an array with the uncommon elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

Here, I have two arrays of different lengths.And an array is to be returned with the values which are uncommon in both the arrays.But the compiler is giving wrong output.What are the issues with these functionalities?
Output:[4,5] in this case instead of [4].

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = [];
  var y=[];
  var z=[];
  // Same, same; but different.
  var flag=0;
  for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    if(arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]===-1)){
      z=arr1.slice(i,i+1);
      //return z;
    }
    for(var j=0;j<arr2.length;j++){
      if(arr1.indexOf(arr2[j])===-1){
        y=arr2.slice(j,j+1);
        //z=arr1.slice(i,i+1);
        //break;
      }
    }
  }
   return newArr.concat(y,z);
}

diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
diffArray(["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"]);
```

Comment: `compiler is giving wrong output` ??

Comment: [4,5] is coming as the output instead of [5] @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: why are you expecting [5]? isn't uncommon element [4]

Comment: yes sorry! Expected output: [4]

Comment: Line 8: you probably meant arr2.indexOf(arr1[i])===-1 (move the last paren).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
function diffArray (arr1, arr2) {
    var z = arr1.filter(function (value) { return !~arr2.indexOf(value); });
    var y = arr2.filter(function (value) { return !~arr1.indexOf(value); });

    return [].concat(y, z);
}
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sure. Thx

Comment: what does !~ operator do? I cant find it on google. @floriangosse

Comment: The `!` is a [Logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) and the `~` is a [Bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT).

Answer (score 1):

You can try an alternative for your function

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3, 5];
a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
result = [];
if (a1.length > a2.length) {
  temp = a1;
  a1 = a2;
  a2 = temp;
}

$.grep(a2, function(k) {
        if ($.inArray(k, a1) == -1) result.push(k);
});
console.log(result);,
```

Here is working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9h7d793/2/) for your both array sets.

Give it a try, this will work.

Comment: in this case,what if the size of arr1 is greater than of arr2? @rahul_m

Comment: I have added condition for lesser and greater both, check if statement

Comment: here in function(k), will it take the values from a2 automatically or do I need to define it somewhere? I am new to javascript

Comment: Yes it will take automatically, its value of array which will be iterated. Once give it a try

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have lines like:

```
z=arr1.slice(i,i+1);
y=arr2.slice(j,j+1);
```

If you do so, each time you get a unique element, you will lose the previous one stored.

Also, `Array.prototype.slice` returns an array, therefore you don't need to use `slice()` as well.

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = [];
  var y=[];
  var z=[];

  var flag=0;
  for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
    if(arr2.indexOf(arr1[i])===-1) {
      z.push(arr1[i]);
    }
  }

  for(var j=0;j<arr2.length;j++) {
    if(arr1.indexOf(arr2[j])===-1) {
      y.push(arr2[j]);
    }
  }

  return y.concat(z);
}
```

This should help you there.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dv0mehkk/) to show the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = [];

  var firstArray = arr1;
  var secondArray = arr2;
  if (arr2.length > arr1.length) {
    firstArray = arr2;
    secondArray = arr1;
  }

  var isNotMatched = false;

  for (var i in firstArray) {
    for (var j in secondArray) {
      if (firstArray[i] !== secondArray[j]) {
        isNotMatched = true;
      } else {
        isNotMatched = false;
        break;
      }

    }

    if (isNotMatched)
      newArr.push(firstArray[i]);

  }

  return newArr;
}

diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

2nd version work for all

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = [];
  var firstArray = arr1;
  var secondArray = arr2;
  if (arr2.length > arr1.length) {
    firstArray = arr2;
    secondArray = arr1;
  }

  var whenSameLegth = '';
  var isNotMatched = false;

  for (var i in firstArray) {
    for (var j in secondArray) {
      if (firstArray[i] !== secondArray[j]) {
        isNotMatched = true;
        whenSameLegth = secondArray[j];
      } else {
        isNotMatched = false;
        break;
      }

    }
    if (isNotMatched && arr2.length === arr1.length) {
      newArr.push(firstArray[i]);
      newArr.push(whenSameLegth);
    } else if (isNotMatched) {
      newArr.push(firstArray[i]);
    }
  }

  return newArr;
}
```

diffArray(["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"]);

Comment: ["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"] should return ["diorite", "pink wool"]. It doesn't work for this! @love-Kesh

Comment: Please check now 2nd verion @aayushi

Answer (score 0):

The code, as written, can only return up to two items, because `y` and `z` are always overwritten with a new array of length one whenever `z=arr1.slice(i,i+1);` or `y=arr2.slice(j,j+1);` are called. You probably want to use Array.push, i.e. `z.push(arr1[i]);` and `y.push(arr2[j]);`. This will add to the same array each time an element is found, rather than reset the result array each time.

Comment: Even with push(), the expected output is not coming! @dncook

Answer (score 0):

You can merge both array and return unique values.

```js
function diffArray(a1, a2){
  var data = a1.concat(a2);
  return data.filter(function(item, i, a){
    return a.indexOf(item) === a.lastIndexOf(item)
  });
}

console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [11, 12, 13, 14, 5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var newArr = [];
    function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {


            arr1.forEach(function (item) {
                if (arr2.indexOf(item) === -1)
                    newArr.push(item);
            });

            arr2.forEach(function (item) {
                if (arr1.indexOf(item) === -1)
                    newArr.push(item);
            });

    }

    diffArray(["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"]);
```

Comment: ["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"] should return ["diorite", "pink wool"] .                        It doesn't work for this ! @Mairaj

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the latest version of JavaScript (ES6), the following should do the trick and run in linear time as opposed to quadratic time — O(N) vs. O(N²).

```js
function diffArray(a, b) {
  a = new Set(a)
  let result = []
  for (let value of b) {
    a.delete(value) || result.push(value)
  }
  result.push(...a)
  return result
}

console.log(diffArray(
  [1, 2, 3, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
))
console.log(diffArray(
  ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"],
  ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"]
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and count the occurence. it works for more than one equla element in an array as well.

```js
function getSymmetricDifference(a1, a2) {
    var hash = {};
    a1.forEach(function (a) {
        (hash[a] = hash[a] || { count: 0, value: a }).count++;
    });
    a2.forEach(function (a) {
        (hash[a] = hash[a] || { count: 0, value: a }).count--;
    });
    return Object.keys(hash).filter(function (a) { return hash[a].count; }).map(function (a) { return hash[a].value; });
}

console.log(getSymmetricDifference([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(getSymmetricDifference(["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"]));
```